# Is there a database of all domino tilings of an n by m rectangle (for small n, m)?

Tags: combinatorics, tiling

I would like to see the actual dominos in all domino tilings of any small rectangle (or similar).  I'm not sure what an efficient algorithm is for constructively enumerating them by computer.  Yes, there are closed form expressions for counting them, but that doesn't help in constructing them (other than verifying that one's algorithm is likely correct).  But it seems to me that once someone, somewhere has done that, the results might be saved somewhere (in some kind of parsable file format) and available to others.  If not, what's the best way to understand how to constructively enumerate all the solutions, at least for small *n* and *m*?

Answer (score 1):

Start with an empty rectangle and traverse the squares from left to right, top to bottom. If you encounter a square that hasn’t been tiled yet, tile it with the square either to its right or below it (if that square exists and is untiled), and recurse.

[Here’s Java code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/20fb175c5902023f741b673bcf3ee503) that implements this approach. It seems to be quite efficient – the number of dead ends reached is about an order of magnitude lower than the number of tilings found. For a non-square rectangle, the number of dead ends reached is lower if you use more rows than columns (which makes sense, as the dead ends occur in the last two rows, no matter how many rows there are, and the rows are shorter this way).

Comment: There certainly will be some dead ends when you are filling the second to last row, and there are even some dead ends caused by placing some vertical dominoes when filling the third to last row (e.g. in the first and third column where the second column is skipped because it is already filled by the bottom half of a vertical domino from the fourth to last row).

Comment: I got a C program working and verified via https://oeis.org/A099390 that it's finding the right counts.  There are some nuances re efficiency.  One needs to avoid wasting too much time searching for the next free square.  The code for this at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3187154/generating-all-possible-domino-tilings-on-a-4-times-4-grid does this badly.  One can also simplify the algorithm by using pre-set sentinel rows/columns in an enlarged array.  Takes about 3 seconds to find (but not record) all 108,435,745 tilings for the 8 x 9 rectangle.  Thx.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis: You're right, I was wrong about that. I removed that claim about dead ends and instead wrote an implementation that counts them – see the revised answer.

Comment: @jsbox: I also implemented the approach (see the revised answer). I didn't optimize for performance; it takes more like $10$ seconds for the $8\times9$ rectangle.

Comment: My C code computes all 165,580,141 (a Fibonacci number) tilings in a 2 high x 40 wide rectangle.  Interestingly, it takes about 13 seconds, which means there's a whole lot more backtracking dead ends happening than for a near-square rectangle.  Because it's all top row.  If I change it to 40 high x 2 wide, the run-time goes back down to around 3 seconds.

Comment: If you care specifically about the $2 \times n$ case, that can be implemented without any dead ends by lifting the Fibonacci recursion.